# Convert a data frame to a matrix of ones and zeros in R

Tags: r

I have got the following Data Frame "j" ...
and want to convert to a matrix of zeros and ones,
like below, but i looking for a more easy way to convert it in R...the matrix represent the positions of the values of the data frame,..For example the matrix is (81x3)...if i have got an  "1" in the df, an "1" will be write in the first column of the matrix, if a have got a "2" in the df, a "1" will be write in the second column of the matrix... thanks!

```
g <- h <- i <- c(1:3)
j<-expand.grid(g,h,i)
j
     Var1 Var2 Var3
1     1    1    1
2     2    1    1
3     3    1    1
4     1    2    1
5     2    2    2
.
.
.
m<-matrix(0,81,3)
m[1,1]=m[1,1]+1;m[2,1]=m[2,1]+1;m[3,1]=m[3,1]+1
m[4,2]=m[4,2]+1;m[5,1]=m[5,1]+1;m[6,1]=m[6,1]+1
m[7,3]=m[7,3]+1;m[8,1]=m[8,1]+1;m[9,1]=m[9,1]+1
m[10,1]=m[10,1]+1;m[11,2]=m[11,2]+1;m[12,1]=m[12,1]+1
m[13,2]=m[13,2]+1;m[14,2]=m[14,2]+1;m[15,1]=m[15,1]+1
m[16,2]=m[16,2]+1;m[17,2]=m[17,2]+1;m[18,2]=m[18,2]+1
head(m)
     [,1] [,2] [,3]

 [1,]    1    0    0
 [2,]    1    0    0
 [3,]    1    0    0
 [4,]    0    1    0
 [5,]    1    0    0
 [6,]    1    0    0
 [7,]    0    0    1
 [8,]    1    0    0
 [9,]    1    0    0
[10,]    1    0    0
[11,]    0    1    0
[12,]    1    0    0
[13,]    0    1    0
[14,]    0    1    0
[15,]    0    1    0
```

Comment: You will have to explain the logic behind what you are wanting. At the moment it is a complete mystery.

Comment: Yes, there doesn't seem to be any relation between `j` and `m`...

Comment: not enough explanation given

Comment: @juba, it's a fuzzy relation, for sure, but it's there....

Answer (score 1):

Feels quirky, but this is what I came up with:

```
g <- h <- i <- c(1:3)
j<-expand.grid(g,h,i)

tmp<-c(0,0,0)
t(sapply(t(j),function(x,tmp){ tmp[x]<-1;tmp }, tmp))
```

Answer (score 0):

@ndoogan's approach works, but it seems like it would make much more sense to just use matrix indexing for this:

Here's your "j" `data.frame`:

```
j <- expand.grid(replicate(3, 1:3, FALSE))
```

And your empty `matrix`, "m":

```
m <- matrix(0, 81, 3)
```

The "i" would just be `1:nrow(m)`, and you can turn your "j" `data.frame` into a `vector` with a simple `c(t(j))`. The `t` is required to get the order you show, otherwise `unlist` could also be used.

Here it is in practice:

```
m[cbind(1:81, c(t(j)))] <- 1
head(m, 10)
#       [,1] [,2] [,3]
#  [1,]    1    0    0
#  [2,]    1    0    0
#  [3,]    1    0    0
#  [4,]    0    1    0
#  [5,]    1    0    0
#  [6,]    1    0    0
#  [7,]    0    0    1
#  [8,]    1    0    0
#  [9,]    1    0    0
# [10,]    1    0    0
```